# PHP Converting string date and time to MySQL DateTime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have two text fields, one for the date in 08/01/2012 format and a second field containing the time. I currently have the time field in the format 09:41am but I have some flexibility with it's format (if 24hr is easier for example).

I was planning on just concatenating the strings and then converting. Should I convert the date to 2012-08-01 first?

How can I end up converting to datetime (2012-08-01 09:41:00)? How to convert back out of it into a 08/01/2012 and 09:41am format?

Comment: See [`strtotime`](php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date`](php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). Concat, `strtotime`, then `date` into whatever format you want.

Comment: So, you are currently storing date and time as plain strings …?

Comment: no, I'm storing as datetime, but I need to show date and time in separate fields on a page. The date has to be in a certain format to work with a jQuery datepicker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(concat('08/01/2012', '09:41am'),'%d/%m/%Y%h:%i');
```

Comment: Perfect, and `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(  '2012-01-08 09:41:00',  '%r' )` to convert back seems to work too. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On the database side, you can use:

`STR_TO_DATE()` using the specifiers in [this table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to convert into a database friendly format. [Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

`DATE_FORMAT()` will then return whatever part you want of that database time. [Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

On the PHP side you can use:

- `strtotime()` - Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp
- `date` - Format a local time/date

`strotime` will produce a Unix timestamp based on any string date/time that is passed to it. If you pass both your fields (08/01/2012 & 09:41am) it will produce a timestamp based on it. To reverse the process, you use `date("m/d/Y H:ia")`.

```
$field1 = '08/01/2012';
$field2 = '09:41am';

$stamp = strtotime($field1 . ' ' . $field2);

echo date("m/d/Y H:ia", $stamp);
```

I have not tested this, but it should work.